# Unity Ai pathfinding rotation up/down hill

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, game-physics, path-finding

Hello so im doing a rts im not that new to c# but i have still alot to learn  i have ai from a* that im using with there a* pathfinding i modify it abit but im aiming to achive this with my ai [image]

so i have a raycast that is casted out of the minion down and it hits to terrain and by it its gonna do the rotation on hills but its not working as you see here 
[image]

so here is the code for raycast part :

```
 RaycastHit hit;
        Ray GroundRay = new Ray(transform.position, -transform.up);

        if (Physics.Raycast(GroundRay, out hit))
        {
            transform.LookAt(transform.position + velocity, hit.normal);
        }
```

and this is the hole ai code i use :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Pathfinding;
using Pathfinding.RVO;
using Pathfinding.Util;

/** AI for following paths.
 * This AI is the default movement script which comes with the A* Pathfinding Project.
 * It is in no way required by the rest of the system, so feel free to write your own. But I hope this script will make it easier
 * to set up movement for the characters in your game.
 * This script works well for many types of units, but if you need the highest performance (for example if you are moving hundreds of characters) you
 * may want to customize this script or write a custom movement script to be able to optimize it specifically for your game.
 * \n
 * \n
 * This script will try to follow a target transform. At regular intervals, the path to that target will be recalculated.
 * It will in the #Update method try to move towards the next point in the path.
 * However it will only move in roughly forward direction (Z+ axis) of the character, but it will rotate around it's Y-axis
 * to make it possible to reach the target.
 *
 * \section variables Quick overview of the variables
 * In the inspector in Unity, you will see a bunch of variables. You can view detailed information further down, but here's a quick overview.\n
 * The #repathRate determines how often it will search for new paths, if you have fast moving targets, you might want to set it to a lower value.\n
 * The #target variable is where the AI will try to move, it can be a point on the ground where the player has clicked in an RTS for example.
 * Or it can be the player object in a zombie game.\n
 * The speed is self-explanatory, so is #rotationSpeed, however #slowdownDistance might require some explanation.
 * It is the approximate distance from the target where the AI will start to slow down.\n
 * #pickNextWaypointDist is simply determines within what range it will switch to target the next waypoint in the path.\n
 *
 * Below is an image illustrating several variables as well as some internal ones, but which are relevant for understanding how it works.
 * \note The image is slightly outdated, replace forwardLook with pickNextWaypointDist in the image and ignore the circle for pickNextWaypointDist.
 *
 * \shadowimage{aipath_variables.png}
 * This script has many movement fallbacks.
 * If it finds an RVOController attached to the same GameObject as this component, it will use that. If it fins a character controller it will also use that.
 * Lastly if will fall back to simply modifying Transform.position which is guaranteed to always work and is also the most performant option.
 */
[RequireComponent(typeof(Seeker))]
[AddComponentMenu("Pathfinding/AI/AIPath (2D,3D)")]
[HelpURL("http://arongranberg.com/astar/docs/class_a_i_path.php")]
public class AIPath : AIBase {
    /** Determines how often it will search for new paths.
     * If you have fast moving targets or AIs, you might want to set it to a lower value.
     * The value is in seconds between path requests.
     */
    public float repathRate = 0.5F;

    /** Target to move towards.
     * The AI will try to follow/move towards this target.
     * It can be a point on the ground where the player has clicked in an RTS for example, or it can be the player object in a zombie game.
     */
    Vector3 target;


    /** Enables or disables searching for paths.
     * Setting this to false does not stop any active path requests from being calculated or stop it from continuing to follow the current path.
     * \see #canMove
     */
    public bool canSearch = true;

    /** Enables or disables movement.
     * \see #canSearch
     */
    public bool canMove = true;

    public bool enableRotation = true; //delete


    /** Maximum velocity.
     * This is the maximum speed in world units per second.
     */
    public float speed = 3;

    /** Rotation speed.
     * Rotation is calculated using Quaternion.RotateTowards. This variable represents the rotation speed in degrees per second.
     * The higher it is, the faster the character will be able to rotate.
     */
    [UnityEngine.Serialization.FormerlySerializedAs("turningSpeed")]
    public float rotationSpeed = 360;

    /** Distance from the target point where the AI will start to slow down.
     * Note that this doesn't only affect the end point of the path
     * but also any intermediate points, so be sure to set #pickNextWaypointDist to a higher value than this
     */
    public float slowdownDistance = 0.6F;

    /** Determines within what range it will switch to target the next waypoint in the path */
    public float pickNextWaypointDist = 2;

    /** Distance to the end point to consider the end of path to be reached.
     * When the end is within this distance then #OnTargetReached will be called and #TargetReached will return true.
     */
    public float endReachedDistance = 0.2F;

    /** Draws detailed gizmos constantly in the scene view instead of only when the agent is selected and settings are being modified */
    public bool alwaysDrawGizmos;

    /** Time when the last path request was sent */
    protected float lastRepath = -9999;

    /** Current path which is followed */
    protected Path path;

    protected PathInterpolator interpolator = new PathInterpolator();

    /** Only when the previous path has been returned should be search for a new path */
    protected bool canSearchAgain = true;

    /** True if the end of the path has been reached */
    public bool TargetReached { get; protected set; }

    /** True if the Start function has been executed.
     * Used to test if coroutines should be started in OnEnable to prevent calculating paths
     * in the awake stage (or rather before start on frame 0).
     */
    private bool startHasRun = false;

    /** Point to where the AI is heading */
    protected Vector3 targetPoint;

    protected Vector3 velocity;

    /** Rotation speed.
     * \deprecated This field has been renamed to #rotationSpeed and is now in degrees per second instead of a damping factor.
     */
    [System.Obsolete("This field has been renamed to #rotationSpeed and is now in degrees per second instead of a damping factor")]
    public float turningSpeed { get { return rotationSpeed/90; } set { rotationSpeed = value*90; } }

    /** Starts searching for paths.
     * If you override this function you should in most cases call base.Start () at the start of it.
     * \see #Init
     */
    protected virtual void Start () {
        startHasRun = true;
        Init();
        target = transform.position;
        canMove = false;
    }

    /** Called when the component is enabled */
    protected virtual void OnEnable () {
        // Make sure we receive callbacks when paths are calculated
        seeker.pathCallback += OnPathComplete;
        Init();
    }





    private void MoveSelectedToCursorPosition()
    {
        RaycastHit raycastHit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out raycastHit, 1000.0f))
        {
            target = raycastHit.point;
            canMove = true;

        }
    }

    void Init () {
        if (startHasRun) {
            lastRepath = float.NegativeInfinity;
            StartCoroutine(RepeatTrySearchPath());
        }

    }

    public void OnDisable () {
        seeker.CancelCurrentPathRequest();

        // Release current path so that it can be pooled
        if (path != null) path.Release(this);
        path = null;

        // Make sure we no longer receive callbacks when paths complete
        seeker.pathCallback -= OnPathComplete;
    }

    /** Tries to search for a path every #repathRate seconds.
     * \see TrySearchPath
     */
    protected IEnumerator RepeatTrySearchPath () {
        while (true) yield return new WaitForSeconds(TrySearchPath());
    }

    /** Tries to search for a path.
     * Will search for a new path if there was a sufficient time since the last repath and both
     * #canSearchAgain and #canSearch are true and there is a target.
     *
     * \returns The time to wait until calling this function again (based on #repathRate)
     */
    public float TrySearchPath () {

        if (Time.time - lastRepath >= repathRate && canSearchAgain && canSearch && target != null) {
            SearchPath();
            return repathRate;
        } else {
            float v = repathRate - (Time.time-lastRepath);
            return v < 0 ? 0 : v;
        }
    }

    /** Requests a path to the target */
    public virtual void SearchPath () {
        if (target == null) throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Target is null");

        lastRepath = Time.time;
        // This is where we should search to
        Vector3 targetPosition = target;

        canSearchAgain = false;

        // Alternative way of requesting the path
        //ABPath p = ABPath.Construct(GetFeetPosition(), targetPosition, null);
        //seeker.StartPath(p);

        // We should search from the current position
        seeker.StartPath(GetFeetPosition(), targetPosition);
    }

    public virtual void OnTargetReached () {
        // The end of the path has been reached.
        // If you want custom logic for when the AI has reached it's destination
        // add it here.
        // You can also create a new script which inherits from this one
        // and override the function in that script
        canMove = false;

    }

    /** Called when a requested path has finished calculation.
     * A path is first requested by #SearchPath, it is then calculated, probably in the same or the next frame.
     * Finally it is returned to the seeker which forwards it to this function.\n
     */
    public virtual void OnPathComplete (Path _p) {
        ABPath p = _p as ABPath;

        if (p == null) throw new System.Exception("This function only handles ABPaths, do not use special path types");

        canSearchAgain = true;

        // Claim the new path
        p.Claim(this);

        // Path couldn't be calculated of some reason.
        // More info in p.errorLog (debug string)
        if (p.error) {
            p.Release(this);
            return;
        }

        // Release the previous path
        if (path != null) path.Release(this);

        // Replace the old path
        path = p;

        // Make sure the path contains at least 2 points
        if (path.vectorPath.Count == 1) path.vectorPath.Add(path.vectorPath[0]);
        interpolator.SetPath(path.vectorPath);

        var graph = AstarData.GetGraph(path.path[0]) as ITransformedGraph;
        movementPlane = graph != null ? graph.transform : GraphTransform.identityTransform;

        // Reset some variables
        TargetReached = false;

        // Simulate movement from the point where the path was requested
        // to where we are right now. This reduces the risk that the agent
        // gets confused because the first point in the path is far away
        // from the current position (possibly behind it which could cause
        // the agent to turn around, and that looks pretty bad).
        interpolator.MoveToLocallyClosestPoint((GetFeetPosition() + p.originalStartPoint) * 0.5f);
        interpolator.MoveToLocallyClosestPoint(GetFeetPosition());
    }

    public virtual Vector3 GetFeetPosition () {
        if (controller != null && controller.enabled) {
            return tr.TransformPoint(controller.center) - Vector3.up*controller.height*0.5F;
        }

        return tr.position;
    }


    /** Called during either Update or FixedUpdate depending on if rigidbodies are used for movement or not */
    protected override void MovementUpdate (float deltaTime) {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            MoveSelectedToCursorPosition();
        }



        if (!canMove) return;

        if (!interpolator.valid) {
            velocity2D = Vector3.zero;
        } else {
            var currentPosition = tr.position;

            interpolator.MoveToLocallyClosestPoint(currentPosition, true, false);
            interpolator.MoveToCircleIntersection2D(currentPosition, pickNextWaypointDist, movementPlane);
            targetPoint = interpolator.position;
            var dir = movementPlane.ToPlane(targetPoint-currentPosition);

            var distanceToEnd = dir.magnitude + interpolator.remainingDistance;
            // How fast to move depending on the distance to the target.
            // Move slower as the character gets closer to the target.
            float slowdown = slowdownDistance > 0 ? distanceToEnd / slowdownDistance : 1;

            // a = v/t, should probably expose as a variable
            float acceleration = speed / 0.4f;
            velocity2D += MovementUtilities.CalculateAccelerationToReachPoint(dir, dir.normalized*speed, velocity2D, acceleration, speed) * deltaTime;
            velocity2D = MovementUtilities.ClampVelocity(velocity2D, speed, slowdown, true, movementPlane.ToPlane(rotationIn2D ? tr.up : tr.forward));



            if (distanceToEnd <= endReachedDistance && !TargetReached) {
                TargetReached = true;
                OnTargetReached();
            }

            // Rotate towards the direction we are moving in
            var currentRotationSpeed = rotationSpeed * Mathf.Clamp01((Mathf.Sqrt(slowdown) - 0.3f) / 0.7f);
            RotateTowards(velocity2D, currentRotationSpeed * deltaTime);

            var delta2D = CalculateDeltaToMoveThisFrame(movementPlane.ToPlane(currentPosition), distanceToEnd, deltaTime);
            Move(currentPosition, movementPlane.ToWorld(delta2D, verticalVelocity * deltaTime));

            velocity = movementPlane.ToWorld(velocity2D, verticalVelocity);
            RotateTowards( velocity , currentRotationSpeed * deltaTime);

        }
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray GroundRay = new Ray(transform.position, -transform.up);

        if (Physics.Raycast(GroundRay, out hit))
        {
            transform.LookAt(transform.position + velocity, hit.normal);
        }
    }

    /** Direction that the agent wants to move in (excluding physics and local avoidance).
     * \deprecated Only exists for compatibility reasons.
     */
    [System.Obsolete("Only exists for compatibility reasons.")]
    public Vector3 targetDirection {
        get {
            return (targetPoint - tr.position).normalized;
        }
    }

    /** Current desired velocity of the agent (excluding physics and local avoidance but it includes gravity).
     * \deprecated This method no longer calculates the velocity. Use the #velocity property instead.
     */
    [System.Obsolete("This method no longer calculates the velocity. Use the velocity property instead")]
    public Vector3 CalculateVelocity (Vector3 position) {
        return velocity;
    }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    [System.NonSerialized]
    int gizmoHash = 0;

    [System.NonSerialized]
    float lastChangedTime = float.NegativeInfinity;

    protected static readonly Color GizmoColor = new Color(46.0f/255, 104.0f/255, 201.0f/255);

    protected override void OnDrawGizmos () {
        base.OnDrawGizmos();
        if (alwaysDrawGizmos) OnDrawGizmosInternal();
    }

    void OnDrawGizmosSelected () {
        if (!alwaysDrawGizmos) OnDrawGizmosInternal();
    }

    void OnDrawGizmosInternal () {

        var newGizmoHash = pickNextWaypointDist.GetHashCode() ^ slowdownDistance.GetHashCode() ^ endReachedDistance.GetHashCode();

        if (newGizmoHash != gizmoHash && gizmoHash != 0) lastChangedTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
        gizmoHash = newGizmoHash;
        float alpha = alwaysDrawGizmos ? 1 : Mathf.SmoothStep(1, 0, (Time.realtimeSinceStartup - lastChangedTime - 5f)/0.5f) * (UnityEditor.Selection.gameObjects.Length == 1 ? 1 : 0);

        if (alpha > 0) {
            // Make sure the scene view is repainted while the gizmos are visible
            if (!alwaysDrawGizmos) UnityEditor.SceneView.RepaintAll();
            if (targetPoint != Vector3.zero) Draw.Gizmos.Line(transform.position, targetPoint, GizmoColor * new Color(1, 1, 1, alpha));
            Gizmos.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(transform.position, transform.rotation, Vector3.one);
            Draw.Gizmos.CircleXZ(Vector3.zero, pickNextWaypointDist, GizmoColor * new Color(1, 1, 1, alpha));
            Draw.Gizmos.CircleXZ(Vector3.zero, slowdownDistance, Color.Lerp(GizmoColor, Color.red, 0.5f) * new Color(1, 1, 1, alpha));
            Draw.Gizmos.CircleXZ(Vector3.zero, endReachedDistance, Color.Lerp(GizmoColor, Color.red, 0.8f) * new Color(1, 1, 1, alpha));
        }
    }
#endif

    protected override int OnUpgradeSerializedData (int version) {
        // Approximately convert from a damping value to a degrees per second value.
        if (version < 1) rotationSpeed *= 90;
        return 1;
    }

}
if there is way to fix it please share . Thanks ^^.
```

Comment: I noticed you asked and deleted this few hours ago. Why do you do that? You have been asking this question for a couple of days now. What do you really expect as an answer that will "solve" your problem?

Comment: yea sorry its just a strange progress and i want a explanation on what im doing wrong with the rotation and how is the best way to make it  so it wont do the same thing anymore in the end .

Comment: Ok but what's your question? You don't have any question yet....

Comment: Im asking for a explanation in what i have done wrong and how to fix it with a example .

Comment: 1.Is this 2D or 3D game? Your first screenshot is in 2D and your seond one is in 3D? Which one? 2.What type of collider is the object using? Terrain?Meash Collider? I am talking about the object you walk on

Comment: The image provided here pretty clearly shows it's a 3D problem..?

Comment: @Bejasc There are two images. The first one that looks like a cat walking a rotated triangle. This was the only image used in his/her other questions. Then another second image that's in 3D....

Comment: @Programmer obviously that image is demonstrating the desired solution.